# Dispach queue and semaphore

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore

I am not sure if I'm doing this right - I want to run a remote URL request asynchronously in the background of my app. The user shall not have to wait. However, because of running in background he might trigger multiple requests. I had no semaphores and concurrency yields exceptions. Hence I believe I must protect the request by a semaphore. When requests finish, I run an update on a MKMapView annotation.
I mean to run requests synchronously in the background.

I have the code below, however, it fails even with the current semaphore implementation.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_t requestSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(requestSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

        MapAnnotation* theAnnotation = (MapAnnotation*)button.property;

        [theAnnotation.data update]; //this must be protected

        [self.mapView removeAnnotation:theAnnotation];
        MapAnnotation* newAnnotation = [theAnnotation.data getMapAnnotation];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
        [self.mapView selectAnnotation:newAnnotation animated:YES];

        dispatch_semaphore_signal(requestSemaphore);
    });
```

I get this error for dispatch_async when I run multiple requests - it works in sequential mode though

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 
reason: 'Cannot remove an observer <MKPopoverBasedAnnotationCalloutController 0x10c86bd50> 
for the key path "annotation.title" from <MKPinAnnotationView 0x11798f490> 
because it is not registered as an observer.'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to cancel any in-progress request before making a new request?

Comment: I mean to run requests synchronously in the background. Basically like a queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use GCD, use an `NSOperationQueue` and operations (which can be block operations for simplicity). Then you can use `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:` to ensure that only one operation (request) is ever being processed at any one time.

Note also that you *must* switch back to the main thread before updating the UI (the map view) or you will get exceptions (this is likely the cause of the exception you see currently).

Comment: The switch back to main thread was the cause of the error. Will use the queue, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you think you need semaphores, just use a serial queue. What is wrong with the following approach?

```
  dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("serial_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(serialQueue, 0), ^{

    // Your URL request code


    // Once you finish downloading you update the UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        MapAnnotation *theAnnotation = (MapAnnotation*)button.property;

        [theAnnotation.data update]; //this must be protected

        [self.mapView removeAnnotation:theAnnotation];
        MapAnnotation* newAnnotation = [theAnnotation.data getMapAnnotation];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
        [self.mapView selectAnnotation:newAnnotation animated:YES];
    };
});
```